# How can I add a template in my ongoing project. (Dependency conflict)

Tags: laravel, templates, npm, package.json

I have a application builded with laravel and it is working already. I need to add a template.

But there is a conflict between app files and template files. *Both of this has files with the same name.* Like different package.json, node_modules etc.

I will add a image about template files. So you can see easily. [image: Here a sample of folders:]

For example there is two package.json file. What should I do? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is that a snapshot of your root folder? I think you should move all your template files inside your root/public folder.

Comment: it is snapshot of app folder from template. why should I move the node_modules and  js files ? The js file and saas file not compiled yet.

Comment: I think you have to merge them

Comment: what about package.json ? how can I handle it ?